# Keep local information for branches

Tags: git, testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci, feature-branch

There is a git repository consisting of frontend and backend where the `main` branch is always deployed to test server X.

The feature branches of our team only change a specific part of the backend. On those branches we want to do testing on our own test server Y. Furthermore, we only deploy *the backend*.

To handle this in GitLab CI, we need to keep this "local" information (which testserver, which part will be deployed) somewhere. We do not want to change it directly in the GitLab CI file because

1. We would need to do it every time we open a feature branch.
2. We do not want to merge it back to `main`.

I can think of two alternatives:

- have a naming convention for our "backend" feature branches and then configure a special job for us in the GitLab CI file. This would probably work but might clutter the GitLab CI file if other teams do that as well.
- have a naming convention for our "backend" feature branches and store relevant information in GitLab variables.

Both alternatives do not feel quite like a perfect solution, so I wonder if I have overlooked something and there is a better way to fulfil the requirements in Git or GitLab.

Comment: Reading your question, I understand "`main` needs to be tested on server X, all feature branches need to ne tested on server Y". This looks like a straightforward thing to implement in a gitlab ci file, so I think I am missing something. Can you describe what I am missing ?

Comment: No, it is: The feature branches of our backend team need to be tested on Y. Feature branches of other teams (frontend, libraries) need to be tested on maybe Z or W. Sorry to be unclear.

Comment: ok, I'd go with the naming convention on branches : `back/*`, `front/*`, `lib/*`, ... branches, have a first step in your CI file which, based on the branch name, stores the target test server in a variable, and use that variable in your deploy+testing step.